# Distinguishing argument value of `None` from the default parameter value of `None`

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to know if the value of an argument is the default vs. user-specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251119/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-the-value-of-an-argument-is-the-default-vs-user-spe)
>   [python - returning a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265695/python-returning-a-default-value)

It is standard practice in Python to use `None` as the default parameter value.

However, this idiomatic usage doesn't work well if client code may use `None` as a legal argument value. In this case, the function cannot tell whether the client code omitted the argument, or whether it explicitly passed `None`. This is not good, unless (by luck) the function's behavior should be the same in both cases.

What is a good solution?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: My duplicate covers this better; the other talks about using `None` as the default without `None` being a legitimate value for the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
_NOT_SET = object()

def some_function(some_arg=_NOT_SET):
    if some_arg is _NOT_SET:
        # ...
```

Any class instance has a unique identity that `is` can tell apart.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid namespace pollution? I guess not, since the default parameter value has will be evaluated when function definition is executed?

Comment: Correct. But if your functions are nicely broken up into modules and classes, you can use the tightest scope available to you - for instance, `_NOT_SET` can be a class member or a module member, without being global to your entire program. Using a name that starts with an underscore also helps - it's Python convention for something that external users shouldn't care about.

Comment: Getting a lot of mileage out of the semaphore trick tonight, Amber. (reference to question about the possible uses of a base object instance)  LOL.  I'm not upvoting this one though,  since Q is duplicate.

Comment: I can only see an ugly way to do that, by saying `def some_function(some_arg = object())`, and then looking up default using `inspec`... I wouldn't want to do that :)

Comment: @mjv That's perfectly fine; I don't do this for the rep. The only reason I added this answer instead of also voting to close is that I don't think the linked duplicate actually addresses max's question very well.

Comment: @Amber, true, the duplicate post is a bit confusing because of it also deals with default values that are not objects. And ;-) about you -or I- not really rep driven  (That's my excuse for not being so high on the leader board, but you on the other hand are doing quite well. Congrats).

Comment: In fact, the proposed duplicate question has an answer which your answer duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11251226/603977

Comment: A more common name for this is simply `_marker` or `_default`. I've never seen `_NOT_SET`, and find it slightly confusing.

Comment: @LennartRegebro I've never seen `_marker` nor `_default` before. I don't think there's really a true common standard for it; everyone uses whatever they're most comfortable with (or whatever is used in the project they first came across using it in).