# Check the number of parameters passed in Python function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in Python and wants to know if there is a simple way to get amount of passed parameters in Python function.

```
a(1, 2, 3) ==>3
a(1, 2) ==>2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting list of parameter names inside python function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582056/getting-list-of-parameter-names-inside-python-function)

Comment: Another possibility [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python).

Comment: And I might as well say this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this by using locals()

It is important to note, that this should be done as ultimately, your first step in your method. If you introduce a new variable in your method, you will change your results. So make sure you follow it this way:

```
def a(a, b, c):
    # make this your first statement
    print(len(locals()))
```

If you did this:

```
def a(a, b, c):
    z = 5
    print(len(locals()))
```

You would end up getting 4, which would not be right for your expected results.

Documentation on [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that you have to do this before you've done any assignments within the function for it to work.

Comment: Thanks @Marius, good call. I changed it, let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks, actually I will use in the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 28):

```
def a(*args, **kwargs):
  print(len(args) + len(kwargs))
```

Comment: I'm giving +1 to this anwer, because argument counting inside a function does make sense only when there are variable amount of them.

Answer (score 1):

you could also change the input for your function to a list, so to have a function:

```
a(your_list)
```

then to know how many arguments have been passed to the function,
you could simply do:

```
print len(your_list)
```

However, this means that you change the input type for your function,
from many input variables to only one, the list(which can have a variable number of elements).