# Python call a function with arguments from a tuple which is larger than the amount of arguments needed

Tags: python, arguments

Additional explanation:

What I want to achieve is

```
call(function,(*args,*toomanyargs)) == (function(*args),*toomanyargs)
call(function_with_varargs,(*args))) == (function_with_varargs(*args))
```

what's the pythonic way to achieve this

Comment: Are you passing in a function as an argument?

Comment: `call` would take 1 function and 1 tuple and pass as many arguments to the function and make a new tuple from the result and the arguments that weren't passed to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out how many positional arguments a function accepts by accessing the `.__code__.co_argcount` attribute:

```
>>> function = lambda a, b, c: a+b+c
>>> function.__code__.co_argcount
3
```

However, that doesn't respect varargs:

```
>>> function = lambda *a: a
>>> function.__code__.co_argcount
0
```

So the more robust solution is to use [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature):

```
import inspect

def call(function, args):
    # count the positional arguments
    params = inspect.signature(function).parameters.values()
    if any(param.kind == inspect.Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL for param in params):
        arg_count = len(args)
    else:
        POSITIONAL_KINDS = {inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY,
                            inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD}
        arg_count = sum(1 for param in params if param.kind in POSITIONAL_KINDS)

    # take as many arguments as the function accepts
    remainder = args[arg_count:]
    args = args[:arg_count]

    return (function(*args),) + tuple(remainder)
```

Demo:

```
>>> function = lambda a, b, c: a+b+c
>>> args = range(5)
>>> call(function, args))
(3, 3, 4)
>>> 
>>> function = lambda a, b, c, *d: a+b+c
>>> args = range(5)
>>> call(function, args))
(3,)
```

Answer (score -2):

One way would be to use `locals()` ([Check the number of parameters passed in Python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073652/check-the-number-of-parameters-passed-in-python-function); https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), and do some math in the body of each function to figure out how many args are left over (unused). You can then return a result which includes a tuple of the unused arguments.

Comment: That only works *inside* the function. It doesn't let you inspect the number of parameters from the outside.

Comment: Oh I get what you're saying now. I guess my (clarified) suggestion would be to write the functions you are passing to `call()` to just take all of the *args and deal with them appropriately.

Comment: Because the `call` function wants to find out how many arguments `function` accepts.